# Apple Watch Update Error

Tags: upgrade, apple-watch, watchos

My Apple Watch Series 2 refuses to update to WatchOS 6.2. The error message on my phone (in Dutch) says "Unable to install update", "An error occurred installing the newest WatchOS version on your Apple Watch" (see image below).

I have tried everything from making extra space available to disconnecting the watch from the phone (which is a reset) and repairing and restoring.

Any ideas what I can do? I have a log file available also.

[image: Error message]

Comment: What procedure do you follow for the restore? Did that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Apparently the problem was with certain updates at Apple. A later update resolved this issue.

Comment: What steps did you need to follow (if any)? I'm having precisely the same issue now, with a Series 5 attempting to upgrade to watchOS 7.